# How do I make a canvas drawn object the same "real world" size on all screens

Tags: android

I am currently trying to make something that is drawn via a painter on a canvas that is the same size on all devices. So there is a certain size like 3 inches wide and I want it to be that width on phones and tablets. How would I do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html use `xdpi` and `ydpi` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pixels per inch parameters (`xdpi` and `ydpi`) in [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html).

Comment: Beat you by 10 seconds :) +1

Comment: Yeah, and somehow yours went to the comments haha.  I'll give you points tho